# How to read the Key from appsettings?

Tags: c#, appsettings

Is it possible to get the key based on app settings value?

for Example;

```
string value = "abcd";
string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[value].ToString();
```

Now, I want the `CustomerCategory` in `key` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(k => 
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[k] == value);
```

Comment: What about `Properties.Settings.Default.CustomerCategory`?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstood your question,
Here's the way to do it.

app.config file should be like this,

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" value="myValue"/>
 </appSettings>
```

And your C# code

```
 string myValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"];
```

Comment: I guess you misunderstood - given `myValue`, how to find the *key* (`myKey`) ....